# How to calculate the size of a file in Android

Tags: java, android, file

I am looking to find the size of a file in Android.  I originally expected it to be as simple as a size() method in File, or something along those lines.  But I haven't been able to find anything.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `file.length()`

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#length%28%29

> The length, in bytes, of the file
>   denoted by this abstract pathname, or
>   0L if the file does not exist. Some
>   operating systems may return 0L for
>   pathnames denoting system-dependent
>   entities such as devices or pipes.

Answer (score 3):

`File.length()`. You were close.

Answer (score 2):

This is another solution.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (REQUEST_GET_IMAGE == requestCode && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    Uri uri = data.getData();
    try {
      ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");
      Log.i("file size", String.valueOf(parcelFileDescriptor.getStatSize()));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      //escape logic here 
    }
  }
}
```